# Ubuntu 22.04 - Is it possible to change PulseAudio's default device automatically on startup?

Tags: 22.04, pulseaudio

Whenever I boot up my Ubuntu machine, my default device for PulseAudio is my screen's speakers, `GM204 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)`.
I want to automatically have it set to my headset, `G933 Wireless Headset Dongle Digital Stereo (IEC958)`.
Is there something like a command I can use or something to do on startup?
Thanks in advance.